# TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops

I have my own private organization and repositories.
I also have multiple directories and all of them work except for the "Microsoft account" directory.

I am able to log into Azure Devops no problem using the Microsoft account directory.

I see my organization and I can go through my repositories, agents, pipelines, everything.
However, I can't change anything. All I get is the error or screens that don't load fully.
Its like its in read only mode.

I went into user settings to check permissions and it lets me in but only so far. It stops loading user lists after selecting groups.
It shows me groups and permissions for everything, however.

When I try and generate a PAT, the screen sits there and says "Loading Tokens..."

The error I see everywhere and in the network responses is:

```
$id: "1"
innerException: null
message: "TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource."
typeName: "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server"
typeKey: "UnauthorizedRequestException"
errorCode: 0
eventId: 3000
```

Exactly like that, nothing there between the quotes.

It also shows up in Red text with just this message:
`TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource.`

To resolve this I have done the following:
Logged out of devops entirely, which seems to log me out of several services.
Switched between my AD accounts while logged in.
I've rebooted my machine(I first started seeing this in VS so I updated and rebooted as part of that)

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Issue appears to have resolved itself, might have been related to this issue: https://twitter.com/MSFT365Status/status/1224351597624537088
Either way I no longer have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> message: "TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this
>   resource.

This looks more like the **anonymous** access error as you said that there's nothing between the quotes.

In azure devops, e.g `PAT generated`, most services have themselves security module. When `user` want to make use of them, it must pass the firstly identity check. If for system, your visit and operate are identified as `anonymous`, it will look like **read-only**.

We ever handled such issue and found it due to the **proxy blocking the traffic**, which also lead him to get the same error when accessing azure devops with vscode.*(Similar with yours)*

You need confirm is there any proxy configured in your side.

If there's no proxy set but still has this issue. *Since Stackflow is a open forum but this is a identity issue.* I strongly suggest you contact [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=4d7c8158-200d-893b-5161-06d00803fd9c) and then attach below info also:

- **Activity id**: You could see this from the `Headers` of `Network`. For our backend, we could use this id to check the exactly stack
  trace.
- **Org name** and **account name**.
- **Fiddler trace**. The mostly useful info we need is fiddler trace.

Comment: No proxy on my end and the issue seems to have resolved itself. its possible it was related to this: https://twitter.com/MSFT365Status/status/1224351597624537088

Comment: Marking this ass the answer. If this hadn't resolved itself then I would have submitted a support ticket but not have known what to include.

Comment: @Swago. Wired, we haven't receive such issues report. Will let my team notice and monitor this effect on azure devops. But anyway, awesome to know it solved.

Comment: @Swago, Don't worry, just comment here. I would tell you what we needed when we investigate and how to achieve them.

Answer (score 2):

Try to sign out and the sign in again,
it's worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few options like setting the PAT in interactive screen or via environment variable or by storing it in a file and echoing that file content to the az devops login or az pipeline create command as mentioned in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=preview-page#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access

However none of them worked. Finally it worked after I changed the token (PAT) in the file
/home//.azure/azuredevops/personalaccesstoken.

Comment: Same anon error message for me as OP [TF400813], when using the azure-devops provider in terraform. Mine was not a proxy issue. Solved by doing an az login in the shell that I was running the terraform. This entailed in the shell (1) adding the devops extension [az extension add --name azure-devops] and (2) doing a devops login and putting in the token when prompted, as instructed in the PAT instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops [ az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/YourOrgHere ]

Comment: *The organization specified in the az devops login must begin with http:// or https:// else the token will never authenticate.

Comment: @joynoele, I had same issue and fixed it following your hint to perform an 'az login' first, so thanks. It just looks like the account that owns the tenant isn't set in the pwsh env vars, so it's basically empty. Doing the az login first sets the account ID var to the tenant ID allowing the system to ID you, and confirm you have privileges to access the devops resources on your tenant.

Answer (score 1):

In my case ([Terraform Azure DevOps Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/guides/authenticating_using_the_personal_access_token#configure-environment-variables)), the release pipeline was failing with error:

```
Error: TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.
```

##### Cause:

In this case, release pipeline required the environment variable `AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN` to be set. But it was not being set because the variable group was not linked to the release pipeline.

##### Solution:

1. Check if the PAT token is valid and not expired.
2. Check if the variable group is linked to the pipeline stages and the evironment variable is being set.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the image pool in my yaml code

```yaml
pool:
  vmimage: 'windows-2019'
```