# TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource when using System.AccessToken in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

in my pipeline, I use [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) as token to call [Release Deployment API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), using `azure-devops-node-api`.

It was working until very recently but now is failing 100% with the above error. I have checked the scope of the token following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope and nothing has changed. Any suggestion on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing this with a different package (which depends on `azure-devops-node-api`)
Your issue is most probably the same, and related to this underlying issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues/419

Reverting to version 1.7.3 of `azure-devops-node-api` should fix it if possible.

Comment: Thank you so so much. You saved me so much time! Another workaround I tried is to set `allowCrossOriginAuthentication` to `true` as mentioned in the ticket

Comment: Ah yes, if setting that is an option, that works as well. For my problem that's not an option since the `azure-devops-node-api` is a dependency of a package i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is nothing in '', it is likely that the system recognizes your access as anonymous access. Sometimes, this problem occurs when agents are used, or when default organizations and projects are reconfigured.

Here are some ways to help you debug this issue:

1. Set the `system.debug` variable to true in your pipeline, and check the "Let Users override this value when running this pipeline" option. This will display a more complete run log to check for the issue.
2. Use the web debugging tool [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).
3. Run the pipeline with opening your browser's Developer Console (usually F12) and check it line by line.

Comment: I am using agents, which I don't have access to. I tried printing out the System.AccessToken info and its length is 1010 chars. So the token is not missing. How do I know which configuration is changed? I have looked at the authorization scope settings and they look correct

Comment: @Motoko You can have a look at the Merlin Liang's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021558/tf400813-the-user-is-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource). The exact cause of the problem may be determined by network diagnosis.