# Azure DevOps OAuth2. TF400813: The user is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: azure-devops, oauth-2.0, azure-devops-rest-api

I have implemented an OAuth2 app for Azure DevOps. My website takes user (User A)  to authorize the app using the below URL.
**Step1**

```
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize?scope=vso.code_full (skipped the other parameters)
```

The above URL  works fine and returns with a code+userInfo after user authorization. Now I get an access token passing the code returned from the app using the below API call.

```
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token
```

I can further fetch all the organizations associated with user's  (User A ) account using the below API call

**Step2**

```
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?api-version=6.0-preview&memberId=xyz
```

Now I want to fetch the repositories inside a particular organization. For that I make the below API call.

**Step3**

```
https://dev.azure.com/**organization_name**/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.0
```

The above URL works fine and returns to the repositories inside the specified organization.

**Everything fine so far.**

Now another user (user B)  is trying to connect with my app and he can authorize the app and my application can fetch the organizations under that authenticated user's account. e.g. everything fine until step2. But it fails on step3 e.g. it fails to fetch the repositories inside user's (user B)  organization. The API call in step3 returns with following error

**TF400813: The user is not authorized to access this resource.**

kindly help.

To further clarify, I suspect that issue is with Authenticated user (user B ) , as the whole process works fine for one authenticated user (user A ) but fails for the other user (user B). So there must be something different with second authenticated user. But I am not sure what is it as I am not an Azure guy.

Also Note that when  I am logged in with User A or User B , I can  view my organizations/projects/repos , also I can add/delete organizations/projects/repos. (**I am the organization Owner**)

Then If I am able to view my organizations/repos with a logged in user , and the same user is authenticating the OAuth app then why the Access token produced by the user is not authorized to access the repos in the User B's account ?

Comment: _The user is not authorized to access this resource_ I imagine that you need to go into Azure DevOps and authorise the user account to access repos

Comment: how do I do that ? like I said I am not an azure guy

Comment: and what is this behavaior from microsoft ? I can login to azure devops and see my repos there , then why can't I access those repos thorough the API whereas I have authenticated the app

Comment: Can "second user" see those repos when logging in? Perhaps you could update your question with User A and User B, then clarify in your question whether User B can see these repos in DevOps or not

Comment: Yes User A and User B both can see their repos ,while logged in into their azure account. And I have have updated my question as well.

Comment: This may be a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021558/tf400813-the-user-is-not-authorized-to-access-this-resource - does your error message actually have empty quotes in it? It would imply the user is not logged in, i.e. an earlier step may have faied and you are actually logging in as an anonymous user.

Comment: @Nick , I already have followed the thread you mentioned , but it's not my case. Like I said , I can fetch the organizations of User B , (proof that I am not an anonymous user) . It fails when trying fetch the repos inside an organization of User B , whereas i works for User A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the missing part here.

It is that I have to go to the organization's settings like at the below URL

```
https://dev.azure.com/my_organization_name/_settings/organizationPolicy
```

[image]

and check the first check box under **Application connection policies** which is **Third party application acces via OAuth**

by checking in this option , I am able to fetch the repos under User B's account as well.

It's a shame that Microsoft has no documentation for this. Another reason to hate Microsoft products.

Comment: Glad you sorted it and awesome that you came back and documented it. This doesn't seem to explain how User A had access though?

Comment: Thanx @Nick.McDermaid , the User A was created long ago. I am not sure how the option of Access Via OAuth is set true for User A's organization. However when I created a new organisation for User A , it by default has this option off . 
So apparently this option is off by default and one needs to turn this on to allow the third party apps to connect to their organisation. 
And BTW , check the brilliance of of Microsoft here , that even if you don't turn this option on , the third party app can still get to your organisation , it only fails to fetch the repos inside the organisation. Pity.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: You've installed a version of the user agent that is incompatible with your Azure DevOps server.

In my case, I downloaded the latest version (3.x) which was much more recent and indeed incompatible with my much older on-premise Azure DevOps server.

If you find yourself in my situation, [try installing the 2.195.2 version](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3662#issuecomment-1048283270) because it is the lowest version that is compatible with Visual Studio 2022.